# Wordpress re-direct if specific user is already logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have two members areas set up within a site. If a user logs in, and then decides to browse around the general website, when they click on the 'Members Area' icon again I want that page to work out which user is logged in, and then re-direct them to the correct members area. If no user is logged in, it should display the log in form.

I currently have the following:

```
<?php 
if ( $session->logged_in ) {
    if ( $username == "user1" ) {
        wp_redirect ( home_url("/members-area-1") );
        exit; }
    } elseif ( $username == "user2" ) {
        wp_redirect ( home_url("/members-area-2") );
        exit; 
    } else {     
?>
```

Currently it doesnt re-direct, it just displays the login form regardless of which user I'm logged in as. Any suggestions on how to make this work correctly?

(Be gentle, I'm still fairly raw when it comes to wordpress and php dev)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    global $current_user;
    if( $current_user->user_login == 'user1' )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url("/members-area-1") );
    }
    elseif( $current_user->user_login == 'user2' )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url("/members-area-2") );
    }
    else
    {
        // logged in but doesn't match
    }
}
```

See [is user logged in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) at codex.

**Update:** To solve the header sent warning issue you can add following code in your `functions.php` file to enable output buffering

```
add_action('init', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');

function callback($buffer) { return $buffer; } // This is not necessury if you don't use callback argument in the ob_start function.
function buffer_start() { ob_start("callback"); }
function buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I've implemented that but I've now run in a 'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...' problem, but hopefully once I solve that I will be up and running.

Comment: You sir, are a gent. That has solved the problem perfectly, many thanks.